# Data type recommendes to save datetime in oracle and java

Tags: java, oracle, java-8, sqldatatypes

I have add a column (name updatedAt) in Oracle database table to save updated datetime.

1. What data type should I choose - Date or Timestamp in oracle?
2. To create a model/domain class for this table in Java, shall I use java.sql.Timestamp or java.time.Instant for this column. Or is there any other better and recommended data type to use in Java? I am using java 17.

Please suggest data type for both java and oracle to save date and time.

Comment: I don't know Java. As of Oracle, it depends on what exactly you want to save. If time up to seconds is OK, then choose DATE. If you need to save fractional seconds, then use TIMESTAMP.

Comment: Assuming you want to update the Oracle database table from Java code, then I also assume that you will be using JDBC. If so, then whatever data type you choose for column `updatedAt` will determine the Java class to use since the Oracle JDBC driver has defined mappings between Java classes and Oracle data types. Hence your second question is moot.

Comment: see which can be better for your data,

Comment: safest is to always use timestamp with local timezone - that I believe is our new recommendation

Comment: @Littlefoot Neither DATE nor TIMESTAMP have the context of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So those types cannot record a moment such as when a modification was made.

Comment: Either `DATE` (s accuracy) or `TIMESTAMP` (µs accuracy) in Oracle. The corresponding type in Java is `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I typically stay away from `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`. I think for simple timestamps the `TIMESTAMP` type is good enough.

Comment: *Why the down-votes and close-votes?* The question may appear at first to be opinion-based and/or vaguely researched. I agree with you, @BasilBourque, there is some research behind it, and the recommendations are clear enough and the facts too, so the question is perfectly answerable.

Comment: @TheImpaler more times than not, data is global and we're finding it's better to have more information than you need than less

Answer (score 1):

> What data type should I choose - Date or Timestamp in oracle?

Whichever you want and/or best represents your data.

In Oracle:

- A `DATE` is a binary data-type consisting of 7 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second. It **ALWAYS** has all those components.
- A `TIMESTAMP` is a binary data-type consisting of 7-13 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute, second and 0-6 bytes for fraction seconds depending on the precision of the timestamp.
- A `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is a binary data-type consisting of 14-20 bytes representing: century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute, second, 7 bytes for time-zone information and 0-6 bytes for fraction seconds depending on the precision of the timestamp.

*Note: None of those data-types store data in any particular human-readable format. The format in which `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP` and `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data types are displayed is controlled by the client application which reads from the database.*

- If you want year-to-integer-second precision then use either `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP(0)` data-types (which you use is personal preference - although there is a slight difference in behaviour if you subtract `DATE`s you get a `NUMBER` data-type representing the difference in days, or fraction of days, and if you subtract `TIMESTAMP`s you get an `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` data-type).
- If you want year-to-fractional-second precision then use the `TIMESTAMP(N)` data-type (where `N` is the desired number of digits precision for the fractional seconds).
- If you want to include a time zone then use the `TIMESTAMP(N) WITH TIME ZONE` data-type (where `N` is the desired number of digits precision for the fractional seconds).

Answer (score 1):

### Record a moment in Oracle database as `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`

To record a moment, a specific point on the timeline, always use a data type akin to the SQL standard type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In Oracle database, the appropriate type has the same name, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. (Other databases may use other names for such a type.)

Be aware that Oracle database actually records the specified time zone information submitted to the databases. Some other databases behave differently. Some databases such as Postgres instead use the specified time zone or offset to adjust each submitted value to an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

I suggest you employ that same policy when submitting any moment that does not need to remember the original time zone. For example, when recording in Java when an object was created (or last modified), use `java.time.Instant` which *always* represents a moment as seen in UTC (an offset of zero).

```
// Record moment when object was created. 
this.created = Instant.now() ;
```

JDBC requires the use of `OffsetDateTime` type rather than `Instant`. Use the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` to make an `Instant` into an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , this.created.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ) ;
```

You said:

> What data type should I choose - Date or Timestamp in oracle?

`DATE` type in Oracle Database stores the following information: century, year, month, date, hour, minute, and second. Note that time zone or offset is not included. Without the context of zone/offset, values of this type are inherently ambiguous. We do not know if a value of noon on January 23, 2024 was meant to be noon in Tokyo, noon in Toulouse, or noon in Toledo Ohio — three very different moments several hours apart.

The `TIMESTAMP` type in Oracle Database extends the `DATE` type to add a fraction of a second. But this type too lacks the context of a zone or offset. So values of this type are also ambiguous.

So neither `DATE` nor `TIMESTAMP` in Oracle Database should be used for recording a moment.

In Oracle Database, record a moment in a column of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

### Use only *java.time* classes

The terribly flawed legacy date-time classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### `OffsetDateTime` for exchanging a moment via JDBC

The `java.sql.Timestamp` class was replaced by `OffsetDateTime` for purposes involving a database via JDBC.

> shall I use java.sql.Timestamp or java.time.Instant for this column

Never use `java.sql.Timestamp` class.

### `Instant` for representing a moment in UTC

Use `java.time.Instant` in your domain model.

To save and retrieve that value in the database, JDBC requires the use of `java.sql.OffsetDateTime`.

```java
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject ( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
myBusinessObject.setSomeMoment( odt.toInstant() ) ;
```

You could use `OffsetDateTime` in your domain model. But that gives the impression that the offset might vary across instances. If you intend to use only offset values of zero hours-minutes-seconds, then `Instant` makes clear your intention.